# Using querySelector to Find Descendant Elements Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

So I've been playing around with querySelector recently and noticed some really odd behaviour when trying to select descendant elements.

Take the following markup as an example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I want to query this DOM tree from the context of the #parent element, I may do the following:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.querySelector('div')
```

This returns the #foo element as expected. Now, if I wanted to get the #bar element by only referencing tag names, I could do either of these:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.querySelector('div div')
parent.querySelector('div > div')
```

Instead, both selector strings return the #foo element, not the #bar element? However, changing the contextual element (#parent) to a span fixes the issue? It seems as if the contextual element influences how it interprets the selector string. Alternatively, jQuery's selector engine performs as expected.

I created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FGtau?editors=101) that illustrated the problem.

I don't think this is a bug because the results are consistent in multiple browsers (I'm using Chrome 37). I suppose my question is; am I missing something? Is this part of the spec? Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar), "Selectors are evaluated against a given element in the context of the entire DOM tree in which the element is located."

That is, it's not a jQuery-style "find an element matching the selector path starting here".

`#parent #foo` definitely matches `div div` and `div > div`, when viewed from the DOM tree level, per the spec.

It "works" when you change `#parent` to a `span` because `#parent #foo` no longer matches `div div`, and `#foo #bar` is the new first match.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm still a bit confused. If the first fragment of a selector string is in fact evaluated against the contextual element than shouldn't `parent.querySelector('div')` select itself? This inconsistency is what I find especially troubling.

Comment: Nope. No *fragments* of the selector string are evaluated against anything. Child elements of the parent are evaluated against the *complete* selector string. `#foo` is matched against `div div`, which works when its parent is a `div`, not when its parent is a `span`.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but having both `parent.querySelector('div')` and `parent.querySelector('div div')` return the same element seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @user141350 I totally agree. Seems like an inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

For me it returns correct result as of today

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"> <p> sample para </p> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
//const div = document.querySelector("div div div").innerHTML;
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const div = parent.querySelector('div div').innerHTML;
document.write(div);
//sample para
const div = parent.querySelector('div div').innerHTML;
document.write(div);
//sample para

</script>

</body>
</html>
```