# Javascript - get child of child

Tags: javascript

How can I set the innner html of a  `span` element in dom that is under `li>a>`?

```
        <li class="first">
          <a>
            <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

I have tried something like this, but nothing was written:

```
element[i].childNodes[1].children.innerHTML = number;
```

Comment: indexes start at 0, and children is a collection

Comment: @Sebas — Text nodes appear in the list of child nodes

Comment: What is `element`? Why not use `firstElementChild`? Why not use `querySelector`?

Comment: @Quentin I stand corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`children` is an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children). `innerHTML` only applies to HTML elements. You need to find the HTML element in the children before using `innerHTML`.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to mix the use of `childNodes` and `children`. Use the former for more compatibility across browsers, use the latter for a simpler approach that lets you consider only element nodes.

```js
var li = document.querySelector("li");
var number = 13;
li.children[0].children[0].innerHTML = number;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">
    <a>
      <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you could just use `querySelector`:

```js
var li = document.querySelector("li");
var number = 13;
li.querySelector("a").innerHTML = number;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">
    <a>
      <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also note that `li.querySelector` will match elements outside of the `li` scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068390/using-queryselector-to-find-descendant-elements-returns-unexpected-results

Comment: @evolutionxbox — It will find an element, within the scope of the li, which matches the selector. It won't match an element outside the scope of the li, although it might use such elements for things on the left hand side of a combinator.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend using jQuery (http://jquery.com)
and then use can simply do

```
$('li > a > span').html('THE INNER HTML HERE');
```

or

```
$('li > a').find('span').html('THE INNER HTML HERE');
```

you can use `.first()` to the result of find() function to get the first element

Comment: (No jQuery tag, jQuery not asked for in question, therefore no need to answer with a jQuery answer)